# What is the $_REQUEST precedence?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

## PHP Superglobal variables

PHP has global variables which can be accessed within any scope of your script. Three of these variables (`$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`) are stored within a fourth variable (`$_REQUEST`).

### [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.

Consider the following example in which a URL is sent and accessed.

```
http://www.example.com/myPage.php?myVar=myVal
```

```php
echo $_GET["myVar"]; // returns "myVal"
```

### [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

An example of this being used is as follows.

```html
<form action="somePage.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="myVar" value="myVal" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

```php
echo $_POST["myVar"]; // returns "myVal"
```

### [`$_COOKIE`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via HTTP Cookies

```php
setcookie("myVar", "myVal", time() + 3600);
echo $_COOKIE["myVar"]; // returns "myVal"
```

### [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

> An associative array that by default contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

---

## Here's the thing

`$_REQUEST` contains all three in one array and is accessed via `$_REQUEST["myVar"]`.

### A random scenario

Let's assume, for whatever reason, that I use the same name for my `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE`.

What would the precedence be for what is stored in `$_REQUEST`.

Assuming I set a sent data through the URL, posted through the form and, set a cookie with the same name as each other (a bizarre scenario, I know).
Lets say I used the name "example".

What would be the output of the following output?

```php
     if ($_REQUEST["example"] == $_GET["example"])    echo "GET";
else if ($_REQUEST["example"] == $_POST["example"])   echo "POST";
else if ($_REQUEST["example"] == $_COOKIE["example"]) echo "COOKIE";
```

### tl;dr

If `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE` all have a value stored with the same name; which one will `$_REQUEST` store under said name?

Comment: for Your question responds this documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Comment: This was meant as more of a reference. I have created a section in the documentation accordingly. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/3392/superglobal-variables-php/29659/suberglobals-explained#t=201704020210390482585)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `php.ini` file there are 2 directives: `request_order` and `variables_order`

> `request_order string`
>
> ```
> This directive describes the order in which PHP registers GET, POST and Cookie variables
> into the _REQUEST array. Registration is done from left to right, newer values override 
> older values.
>
> If this directive is not set, variables_order is used for $_REQUEST contents.
>
> Note that the default distribution php.ini files does not contain the 'C' for cookies, 
> due to security concerns.
> ```

and

> `variables_order string`
>
> ```
> Sets the order of the EGPCS (Environment, Get, Post, Cookie, and Server) variable 
> parsing. For example, if variables_order is set to "SP" then PHP will create the 
> superglobals $_SERVER and $_POST, but not create $_ENV, $_GET, and $_COOKIE. Setting 
> to "" means no superglobals will be set.
>
> If the deprecated register_globals directive is on, then variables_order also configures 
> the order the ENV, GET, POST, COOKIE and SERVER variables are populated in global scope. 
> So for example if variables_order is set to "EGPCS", register_globals is enabled, and both 
> $_GET['action'] and $_POST['action'] are set, then $action will contain the value of 
> $_POST['action'] as P comes after G in our example directive value.
> ```

Taken from [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order)

Comment: I'd suggest linking your comment within your answer as the saying goes "Teach a Man To Fish".

Answer (score 6):

You have a line in the `php.ini` file that describe `variables_order`. for example:

```
variables_order = "GPC"
```

`G` is Get, `P` is Post and `C` is cookie.
In this case at the first Get variables is set to `$_REQUEST`, next Post variables is set to it and at the last Cookie variables is set to it. So priority is for cookie, then for Post and then for Get.

You can change the priority as you want by changing the value of `variables_order` in `php.ini` file.

P.S: You can write G,P,C,S and E in value of `variables_order`. S is for Session and E is for Environment variables.

P.S: In PHP 5.3 introduced `request_order` directive in `php.ini` file that set the order of setting variables directly in `$_REQUEST` array.